# ListView inside ScrollView makes adapter call multiple times

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, adapter, cardview

Here is the sample code,

contact.xml

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:layout_marginBottom="55dp">

<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        style="@style/ContentFrame"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/msg_listview_frame"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <com.android.bundle.helper.NonScrollListView
                android:id="@+id/contact_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:divider="@color/white_lilac"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                android:scrollbars="none">
            </com.android.bundle.helper.NonScrollListView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

To make ListView non-scrollable, I'm using this custom class NonScrollListView.

NonScrollListView.java

```
public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {

public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
    params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
}
}
```

The adapter is been called more than 40 times, I have tried a couple of options from StackOverflow like changing listview height = fill_parent as well as match_parent.

I know this is an old issue, I'm new to android not able to resolve this one. Kindly help to resolve this issue.

Note: At any cost, ListView has to be inside ScrollView. I want to make CardView be scrollable.

Thanks

Comment: Why using a ListView if you display all the items? Use an empty LinearLayout and add the items dynamically. It's a bad idea to use a ListView inside a ScrollView.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Es

Comment: Thanks for replying @Eselfar. Adding the items dynamically works well but I'm not sure how to use item click listener for a list of same items in the linearlayout like 'listview.setOnItemClickListener'.

Comment: There are different options but what you can do is to create a View.onClickListener and then set it to every children of your LinearLayout. Then in the onClick you can do: int position = linear.indexOfChild(view). (I assume you have a 'linear' variable containing a reference to your linear layout.) The 'view' object is the object returned by the onClick method, it corresponds to the clicked child. Then you can use the position to find the corresponding contact in the array you've used to create the displayed list.

Comment: Thanks @Eselfar. It works.